# Css best way to center text vetically

Tags: css, position

Hi can anyone help me with css positioning please? I have this layout http://jsfiddle.net/9r7NW/2/ And I want the TITLE to be vertically centered, but I don't know how to do it when the higth of its parent can isn't fixed

Comment: This has already been asked 1000 times. Go look at an existing answer.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables bestNameEver.sql

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div id="floater">
<div id="content">
    Content here
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#floater    {float:left; height:50%; margin-bottom:-120px;}
#content    {clear:both; height:240px; position:relative;}
```

Straight from [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=vertically+center+css&sugexp=chrome,mod=6&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Use it.